# Pausing an IPython script with a shell command?

Tags: python, shell, unix, ipython

I have a cpu intensive script I'm running in ipython that will take several days to finish. As I'm using my computer over these days, I would ideally like to be able to pause this script using some ipython shortcut (something along the lines of ctrl+c or ctrl+z) to temporarily reclaim full computing power. Is there any way this might be done?

I'm running IPython directly in the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks!

Comment: One way to deal with this is to run the script with the [nice](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=nice) command. That way, your script does not hog the processing power, but it will take longer.

Comment: What's wrong with Ctrl-Z?

Comment: As @user2357112 alludes to - use the shell's job management. See https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/ctrl-z-stop-restart-linux-jobs.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to spin up a server on Digital Ocean or AWS EC2 and do it that way? The cost will be peanuts for only a few days and it won't be as disruptive.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at kill and signal.

Suppose you have this running in your "IPython"

```
import time
i = 0
while True:
    print('Printing: ', i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    i += 1
```

Now open a new terminal window and type:

```
kill -SIGSTOP `pgrep ipython`
```

If you check your IPython terminal, it has stopped printing.

If you type:

```
kill -SIGCONT `pgrep ipython`
```

Your program will continue where it was stopped.

EDIT: Please note that the characters surrounding *pgrep ipython* are *not* single quotes; they're called "backticks". You can find out how to type them for your system/keyboard layout/etc.

EDIT: The command stops and continues all IPython processes. In reality, if you want to stop/continue a specific process, you have to give it a PID. It's a good idea to put your program in a file and grep for that.